# Fechas aleatorias en php

Tags: php, php7, php5

Hola amig@s estoy aprendiendo php, en el momento queria crear una parte de mi app la cual consiste en agendar una cita, pero debe darme 3 fechas aleatorias deben ser superiores al dia de hoy , las fechas que me de el sistema deben ser 3 y deben ser superiores 15 dias a la fecha actual, que el usuario ingrese al sistema a solicitar la cita, en el momento tengo este codigo, utilice rand, pero es solo para enteros no se como generar y comparar las fechas, este es mi codigo

```
<?php

$diaActual = date('o-n-j');

$diaAleatorio = rand(date('o-n-j'));
$dias         = 15;

if ($diaAleatorio > $diaActual && $diaAleatorio < $dias) {

    echo "El dia de agendamiento de cita es " . $diaAleatorio;
}
```

Comment: Por qué no pruebas a cojer la fecha actual y sumarle una cantidad de días aleatoria?

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacer esto sería cojer la fecha actual y sumarle una cantidad de días aleatoria. Por ejemplo podrías hacer:

```
$fecha_actual = date("d-m-Y"); // hoy
$dias = random_int(1, 100)+15;   // Genero un int entre 1 y 100. Sumo 15 para los 15 días siguientes requeridos
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."+ ".$dias." days"));
```

En tu caso, puedes añadir un bucle en el que recalcules el número de días aleatorio y se lo sumes, para obtener esas tres fechas que necesitas.

Comment: Hola jakala me esta funcionando la fecha, pero me esta sacando dias menores al la fecha actual y no superiores a hoy, que sera?

Answer (score 0):

Usando la función [`rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php) obtienes un entero aleatorio entre los valores proporcionados; con `strtotime()` agregas esos días a la fecha actual, obteniendo un timestamp que puedes formatear con `date()`:

```
$dias = rand(1, 15);
$fecha = strtotime("+$dias days");
echo date('Y-m-d', $fecha);
```